# get values of selected checkbox seperated by comma using jquery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery

i made a checklist of some products to be selected for which i am using jquery to get the values the problem is the code i am using is working in jquery 1.7.2 but not working in jquery 1.9.1 . the error i get is on wrong syntax being used .

```
var output = jQuery.map($(':checkbox[name=vendor\[\]]:checked'), function(n, i){
      return n.value;
}).join(',');
```

The html format is

```
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="vendor[]" value="Event Venue">
            <label for="eventvenue">Event Venue</label></p> 
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="vendor[]" value="Decorations & Rentals">
            <label for="decorations">Decorations & Rentals</label></p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="vendor[]" value="Florist">
            <label for="florist">Florist</label></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var output = jQuery.map($(':checkbox[name="vendor[]"]:checked'), function(n, i){
      return n.value;
}).join(',');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VAten/1/)

Comment: @johnplayer: The old backslash-escaped thing was a jQuery-specific thing which caused all sorts of problems and eventually got dropped (as you discovered). Arun's version is the correct way to do that selector in CSS (which jQuery now handles correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var output = jQuery.map($(':checkbox[name^=vendor]:checked'), function(n, i){
      return n.value;
}).join(',');
```